# How to resize a texture maintaining aspect ratio in libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I have a `.png` image `"circle.png"`.
The problem is when I try to **resize** this in `sb.draw()` method it **disorientates** (stretches). It works fine when I draw it with it's default size;

```
    // inside constructor 
{
        Texture texture = new Texture("circle.png");
        ...
        .
}

// render method
public void render (SpriteBatch sb){
sb.begin();
sb.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
sb.draw(texture,x,y,100,100);// 100 for both width and height
sb.end();
}
```

> //camera setup

```
camera = new OrthographicCamera();
camera.setToOrtho(false, width / 2, height / 2);
```

// width n height is 480x640

First image is one **without resizing**
Second image is **while resizing**
[image: without resizing][image: while resizing]

Comment: Can you show your code for how you realize it?

Comment: when i use just sb.draw(texture,x,y); //params : x,y is the offset on screen
the images draws in its original dimension and aspect ratio

bt when i use sb.draw(texture,x,y,100,100); //params: 100,100 is for width and height of the texture

the image gets stretched

Answer (score 2):

Your image is probably not a square. To maintain the aspect ratio, use math:

```
100 = texture.getWidth()/a
a = texture.getWidth()/100
```

So use:

```
sb.draw(texture,x,y,100,texture.getHeight()/(texture.getWidth()/100);
```

I hope it helps!
staticcasty